# How to expose the x-token from server side in express

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I have the following auth route in the backend of my API:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validate(req.body); 
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

let user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });     
if (!user) return res.status(400).send('Invalid username or password.');  

const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
if (!validPassword) return res.status(400).send('Invalid username or password.');

const token = user.generateAuthToken();
res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'X-OBSERVATORY-AUTH');
res.header('X-OBSERVATORY-AUTH', token).send(_.pick(user, ['_id', 'email', 'username','isAdmin']));
});
```

And in the frontend i have the following handler for the login:

```
login( username: string,  password: string) {
  var user: User = {  username: username, password: password };
this.http
  .post<any>("http://localhost:3000/api/auth",user, {observe:'response'})
  .subscribe((res) => {
    const token = res.headers.get('X-OBSERVATORY-AUTH');
    this.token = token;
    console.log(res.headers.get('X-OBSERVATORY-AUTH'));
    if (token!==null) {
      this.isAuthenticated = true;
      this.userId = res.body._id;
      this.isAdmin=res.body.isAdmin;
      this.authStatusListener.next(true);
      this.saveAuthData(token, this.userId, this.isAdmin); 
    }
  });
}
```

What I am trying to do is to pass the X-OBSERVATORY-AUTH in the response header but I cant figure how to expose the token from the backend. What should I do?

Comment: What does the `console.log` say? Also what's the type of `this.http`?

Comment: The console.log returns null. this.http is .post!

Comment: I mean which __type__. What module exactly did you use for it? Can you add the full `import` statement?

Comment: import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";                                                                 
    import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
    import { Router } from "@angular/router";
    import { Subject } from "rxjs";
    import { User } from "../model/user";
    import {Headers} from "@angular/http";

    var headers = new Headers();

Comment: @molamk sorry for the bad form

Comment: No worries. This is strange though, can you `console.log` the whole response and edit the output __in your question__?

Comment: The only this that is returned in a null. No errors either. In the response header ican see the X-OBSERVATORY-AUTH.

Comment: Try putting `console.log(res)`, then edit your question to include the log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189092/discussion-between-giannis-and-molamk).